# apache cassandra dependencies issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

i'm following a tutorial to understand how cassandra works,
but i have a problem with an import

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
```

this import is not recognized, especially this row:

```
javaFunctions(productsRDD, Product.class).saveToCassandra("java_api", "products");
```

my pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.sparkexamples</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandraExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>cassandraExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

how i can fix it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this import, you are following the old API.

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your /.m2/ directory for the Spark connector jar file. If it's not present, do a `mvn -U` which will force update the dependencies. If it's there, delete that directory from .m2 (only the Spark connector directory) and do a `mvn clean compile>` which should download the jar file again.

If you're working with Eclipse and not CLI, then you can right click on the project in Eclipse -> Maven -> Update project. Not sure about how it works in Netbeans/IntelliJ but there must be similar options there as well.

Also please check if your mvn can connect to the internet from your system. I hope this is not the case but there could be a chance the your mvn could be working offline.

Please check your pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please check if this is causing duplicates and there is a conflicting jar.

Comment: i'm using eclipse, i updated the project, but the problem still reamins

Comment: Did you check your .m2 folder for the jar file to see if it is there?

Comment: i have a lot of dependencies on my .m2 folder, so what jar i ahve to check?

Comment: It will be grouped as folders. folder name would be the jar file's group name. you can navigate to com/datastax/spark or something similar. If you're on linux, you can do a `find ~/.m2 -name '<jar_file_name>` and get it. But otherwise you can always navigate the file system.

Comment: in the folder com.datastax.spark i have two sub folders,  `spark_cassandra-connector_2.10 ` and  `spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 ` p.s i deleted and then donwloaded again the dependecies, but the problem persist.

Comment: Please check my edit to the answer and check your pom.

Comment: You still have 2 spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 . why?

Comment: they are different. One ends with -java-2.10